# How can I control a timer in android?

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer, timertask

I want to make an application about mini game.
Detail : In 2 seconds you must to answer a question if you don't answer or the answer is wrong -> Game Over . But if your answer is true the Timer will reset become 0 and countdown again with diffirent question.

I have already seen many code about timer in website but I don't understand clearly about it :(

So I want to ask : How can i set up a timer run only 2 seconds and how can i reset it and continue with a new question ?

Please help me.

Comment: You should include examples of what you have found, and explain what you didn't understand. As is, this question will attract wild guesses of others who will do nothing but google, as seen below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We want to use the Timer class.

```
private Timer timer;
```

When you're ready for the timer to start counting -- let's say it's after you press a certain button -- do this to start it:

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(incrementTime(), 0, 100);
```

The first line is us creating a new Timer. Pretty standard. The second line, however, is the one I wanted you to see.

incrementTime() is a method that is called at the end of every "tick" of the clock. This method can be called whatever you want, but it has to return an instance of TimerTask. You could even make an anonymous interface if you want, but I prefer moving it off into its own section of code.

The 0 is our starting location. We start counting from here. Simple.

The 100 is how large a "tick" of the clock is (in milliseconds). Here, it's every 100 milliseconds, or every 1/10 of a second. I used this value at the time of writing this code because I was making a stopwatch application and I wanted my clock to change every 0.1 seconds.

As for your project, I'd suggest making the timer's task be your question switch method. Make it happen every 2000 milliseconds, or 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

you can use CountDownTimer in android like this:

```
 public class Myclass {
      myTimer timer =new myTimer(2000,1000);
     public void creatQuestion(){
         timer.start();
        //method you init question and show it to user
     }
     public void getUserAnswer(/*evry thing you expected*/)
     {
         //if answer is true call timer.start()
        //else call  timer.onFinish(); to run onfinish in timer
     }
    public class myTimer extends CountDownTimer {
          public myTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
          }

          @Override
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               // you can update ui here
          }

         @Override
         public void onFinish() {
             this.cancel();
             //fire game over event
           }
    }

}
```

i hope it make you satisfy

Comment: Thank you . Can you give me your email ? I have some questions about CountDownTimer . Can you help me ?

Comment: alimohammadi7117[at]gmail.com

Comment: hi ali,
do you check your email ?

Comment: Yes, I got it .
I have some question to you in new email. Can you check it ?
Thank you a lot :)

Comment: i replied answer to you

Comment: Please check mail again !

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar using Thread/Runnable.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        final long startTime = getTime();
        final long maxEndTime = startTime + 2000L;
        try {
            while (shouldContinueWaiting()) {
                if (getTime() > maxEndTime) {
                    throw new TimeoutException();
                }
                sleep();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            handleInterrupt();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            handleTimeout();
        }
    }


    boolean shouldContinueWaiting() {
        // Has the user already answered?
    }

    void handleInterrupt() {
        // The user has answered. Dispose of this thread.
    }

    void handleTimeout() {
        // User didn't answer in time
    }

    void sleep() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DURATION_IN_MILLIS);
    }

    void getTime() {
         return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

then you can start/restart the thread by:

```
t = new Thread(same as above...);
t.start();
```

and stop by:

```
t.interrupt();
```

Comment: Sure, since you need to implement it.

`long getTime() {
         return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }`

for example

Comment: I don't understand between shouldContinueWaiting() - handleInterrupt().
Where can I code Resume a question, reset a coutdown if User awnser true @@

Comment: Resuming a question, you mean not reseting the timer? Then you would need to calculate the diff between the "startTime" and the current time and remove that value from the "total time allowed for a question" (in my example 2000ms

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. I forgot it , I want reset the timer :(
How can I do it ? 
 void handleInterrupt() : I can create a question and check true/false ? Right ? 
I don't understand 
boolean shouldContinueWaiting() {
        // Has the user already answered?

Comment: "How can I do it?" Read my last comment.

in the case when "shouldContinueWaiting()" returns false, it means the user has answered, so there is no need to wait anymore

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Handler.

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //this will happen after 2000 ms
    }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    // FIRE GAME OVER
    handler.postDelayed(this, 2000); // set time here to refresh textView
}
});
```

- You can fire your game over after 2000 milliseconds.
- If you get the question correct -> remove callback from handler and reset it when the next question starts.